# Can I replace the horrible tiles system with the legacy explorer system?

Tags: windows-10

When right clicking on the Windows 10 start menu, you get a list of options like `Apps & Features`, `Power Options`, etc...

Let's say I click on `System`. I want to replace the window that opens up with the legacy `System` window (`Control Panel` > `System`) rather than the horrible tiles version.

Pictures:

When clicking here:

[image]

I want this screen:

[image: this screen]

to open up rather than this screen:

[image: this screen]

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a free program called [Win+X Menu Editor](https://winaero.com/download.php?view.21) that will allow you to do this.

This is the first screen you'll see when you open the program:

[image]

1. Select the System icon, then click remove.
2. Click Add a program > Add a Control Panel item...
3. Type System in the filter and select it.
4. Use the arrows on the right side to change the position of the icon.
5. Click Restart Explorer to accept the changes.